# Why does Rails generate a config.ru that runs a class, not an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Rack [specifies](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html)

> A Rack application is a Ruby object (not a class) that responds to call.

Consequently, a simple `config.ru` looks like this:

```
class MyApp
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello from Rack!\n"]]
  end
end

run MyApp.new
```

while Rails generates this:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run RailsApp::Application
```

So, I'm wondering: Why not `run RailsApp::Application.new` when Rack specifies it to be an object, not a class? Is there something special about `Rails::Application` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is indeed a bit hidden :)

`RailsApp::Application` is a child class of `Rails::Application`, which in turn is a `Rails::Engine` which is a `Rails::Railtie`. Now `Rails::Railtie` has an [`inherited` hook](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb#L129-L134) which is called whenever a child class inherits from the Railtie class (in this case `Engine`).

This callback includes the [`Rails::Railtie::Configurable`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb) module into the subclass. In this module, you find the first part of the magic.

The `method_missing` method which gets defined on the class calls the method on an instance of the class, which more or less resolves to

```
RailsApp::Application.new.call(...)
```

This `call` instance method is defined in [`Rails::Application#call`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L221-L224) and does the typical Rack handing.

There is probably still a bit more magic involved which makes it not 100% equivalent but that should roughly be it...

Answer (score 1):

A Class is also an Object. Rack doesn't instantiate the app object (which is why it specifies you need to provide the object), you do that in `config.ru`, so provided the Rails class object follows all the Rack rules when Rack sends 'call', it should not be a problem.

Internally, I don't know whether Rails does anything special on `call`. It could even be a factory method that both spits out an instance of the application class and runs it. But it doesn't need to be to satisfy Rack.